# Filter a list by using .StartsWith and a Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, linq

I have this class:

```
public class SimpleUser
{
    public int ProviderID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool ExistingUser { get; set; }
}
```

I have a List that I am filtering by the first letter of a property with in the object.  This works great:

```
List<SimpleUser> filtersList = originalList.Where(s => s.LastName.StartsWith(alpaPage)).ToList();
```

But, here's my catch.  For whatever reason, there are rows in this data where `LastName` is not a letter.  Example: `Contractor #2` where `#2` is the last name.  So on the UI, I give the users a list of filtering options. Like:

- 123
- A
- B
- C

Etc.  If they click on A, B, or C... no problem. But if they click on 123, now I need a separate filter to look for any `LastName` that does not start with a letter.

I'm pretty sure Regular Expressions will be involved here, but I am not seeing how to put all of this together.

```
List<SimpleUser> filtersList = originalList.Where(s => s.LastName.StartsWith(?????)).ToList();
```

I believe my regex would be

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

But please correct me if I'm wrong.  So I've got:

```
var regEx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]");
```

But after that. I'm lost.  `.StartsWith(...` does not seem to take a RegEx.  How do I format this?!?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just check the first char of the string and see if its _not_ `char.IsLetter()`, so `.Where(s => !char.IsLetter(s.LastName.First()))`

Comment: `!char.IsLetter(s.LastName[0])`?

Comment: @maccettura, but I need to check for anything other than a-z or A-Z.  Not just digits.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, that looks promising but would that work in the whole Link statement?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston assuming that `originalList` is a regular list _(not an SQL query, for example)_, yes it should work.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, ok but can you show me the entire syntax?  I'm playing around in VS and I'm not understanding how to use `IsLetter` in a linq statement.

Comment: Try the one in @maccettura's comment. He already edited his comment and included a full query which works like what I suggested. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this simple code:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>() { "aBC", "1asdf", "123fasdf", "a1" };

strList = strList.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[^a-zA-Z].+")).ToList();
```

Details: pattern `^[^a-zA-Z].+` will match string that start with character other than letter (upper or lowercase). Then, I use `IsMatch` method to see if match succeded.

So, in your case, you could put together your pattern like this:

```
string pattern = alpaPage + ".+";
```

In case of `123` option, `alpaPage` should equal to `[^a-zA-Z]`.

Conclusion: use `originalList.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.LastName, @"^[^a-zA-Z].+").ToList();`

Comment: You can use `Regex.IsMatch`, it is shorter

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I was thinking about it when writing explanation :D

Comment: ok, this almost makes sense! See my edits to the OP.  I added the actual class so you can better see what's going on.  I need to be checking on `LastName` only.  The example you gave here doesn't seem to be specific to any property in the list?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston See updated answer. It should provide you with enough information on how to use it.

Comment: ok ok!  Forgive me... I'm just not figuring out how to specify that I am only filtering on LastName, when using a RegEx, I mean

Comment: In your example, which property in the class am I actually filtering on?

Comment: Ah! Sorry.. missed this: `s.LastName`

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you in any way :) Excuse me. I think you can copy paste code from conclusion and it should work for the case you specified.

Answer (score 1):

I think Regex is an overkill for this. As mentioned in the comments, a simple [`char.IsLetter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter) check on the first character of the `LastName` should do just fine:

```
List<SimpleUser> filtersList = 
    originalList.Where(s => !char.IsLetter(s.LastName[0])).ToList();
```

**Complete example:**

```
var originalList = new List<SimpleUser>()
{
    new SimpleUser() { LastName = "aaa" },
    new SimpleUser() { LastName = "bbb" },
    new SimpleUser() { LastName = "123" },
    new SimpleUser() { LastName = "#2" },
};

List<SimpleUser> filtersList = 
    originalList.Where(s => !char.IsLetter(s.LastName[0])).ToList();

foreach (var user in filtersList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.LastName);
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
#2
```